# Node.js data validation with multiple processes

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql, asynchronous

I noticed that in node.js not so easy to validate data in db. For example I have next snippet of code

```
return dbService.checkPossibilityAddEntityBySomeData(t, data)
            .then(function(itPossibleAdd) {
                if(!itPossibleAdd) {
                    throw new Error();
                }
                return dbService.add(t, entity);
            })
```

I add the new entity, if the query returns true. 
But I was faced with situation that multiple processes tried add same entity and when one process conducted validation but still not add entity another process already add this entity. And as a result I get wrong data in the database. 
How to deal with it ?

Comment: How are you checking to see if an entity exists?

Comment: It's query to the database. I have certain criteria to check on the possibility add a new entity.

Comment: I've changed the example for greater understanding

Comment: The fact that the addition of a new entity affect the validation result

Comment: I've done something similar to this.

    function lookup() {
    mFinder(function (listData) {
    if(listData.length > 0){ //Exit because theres no resultset}
    else{//Evaluate the resultset for listData}

Comment: This has no bearing on Node.js, you just do not use the SQL right.

Comment: What is wrong here ? For example, I can add a limited number of entries depending on user roles and for that I need check numbers of entries .